# How to concatenate values of observables used in a text binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

After populating the data of users, I would like to display their full name as list elements.

The data binding is set as following:

```html
<ul id="availableOwners">
    <!-- ko foreach: OwnersList-->
    <li data-bind="text: FirstName, click: AddOwnerToUser.bind($data), value: Id" style="cursor: pointer"></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

I wanted to display the full name with javascript function:

```html
<li data-bind="text: function() { return FirstName + ' ' + LastName }, click: AddOwnerToUser.bind($data), value: Id" style="cursor: pointer"></li>
```

However, it displays the listing of the function definition *literally* as follows:

> `function () { return FirstName + ' ' + LastName}`
>   `function () { return FirstName + ' ' + LastName}`
>   `function () { return FirstName + ' ' + LastName}`
>   `...`

Does anyone know how to display full names correctly in case of binding the list this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To concatenate multiple `observables` together you need to evaluate them by use `()`.

E.g:

```html
<li data-bind="text: FirstName() + ' ' + LastName(), click:AddOwnerToUser.bind($data), value: Id" style="cursor:pointer"></li>
```

However, *ideally*, you should use a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) instead:

```javascript
self.FullName = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.Firstname() + ' ' + self.LastName();
}
```

```html
<li data-bind="text: FullName, click:AddOwnerToUser.bind($data), value: Id" style="cursor:pointer"></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

With more complicated models, instead of over-filling your view/html file, you might consider using a computed observable:

```
this.FullName = ko.computed(function () {
    return this.Firstname() + ' ' + this.LastName();
}
```